# Как работать с римскими числами на java

Tags: java

Всем привет!
Есть задание: написать калькулятор

- Калькулятор умеет работать с арабскими и римскими числами
- должен принимать на вход числа от 1 до 10 включительно, не более
- Калькулятор умеет работать только с целыми числами

Код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value1 = 0;
        int value2 = 0;
        String operation = null;

        System.out.println("Введите 2  целых числа: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (value1 > 0 || value1 < 10) {
            value1 = scanner.nextInt();
            operation = scanner.next();
            value2 = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        if (operation.equals("+")) {
            System.out.println(value1 + value2);
        }
        if (operation.equals("-")) {
            System.out.println(value1 - value2);
        }
        if (operation.equals("*")) {
            System.out.println(value1 * value2);
        }
        if (operation.equals("/")) {
            System.out.println(value1 / value2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос: как тоже самое сделать с римскими числами?

Comment: *как тоже самое сделать с римскими числами?* Конвертировать в арабские (до вычисления) и обратно (соответственно после).

Comment: Для этого вы должны циклически парсить строку. Решение в лоб: запишите в массив римские цифры до 10, и сравнивайте их с найденными римскими цифрами в строке.

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать перечисление и определить в нём нужные вам методы конвертации

```
enum RomanNumeral {
  I("I", 1), IV("IV", 4);...и т.д.

  private int value;
  private String key;

  RomanNumeral(String key, int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
    public String getKey() {
      return key;
    }
    static int toInt(String key) {
      for (RomanNumeral i: this.values())
        if (i.getKey.equals(key))
          return i.getValue();

      return "";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте для себя собственный словарь

```
string [] arab = new string[10]{"10","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};
string [] rome = new string[10]{"X","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"};
```

и соответственно менять по индексу, сперва определив нужный вам цифру.

Answer (score 0):

Вам потребуется два дополнительных метода: один будет переводить любое арабское число в римское, а другой - любое римское в арабское.

К примеру, вам пришли строки `"IV"` и `"X"`. Сначала, вы переводите каждую в арабское число, потом производите с ними математическую операцию так же, как и делаете сейчас, а затем результат конвертируете обратно в римскую систему.
Примеров логики конвертации множество, например, [вот этот](https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-roman-arabic).